# convert vb date comparison to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime

I have a code in vb, and I'm trying convert it to c#.

```
_nextContactDate.ToShortDateString > New Date(1900, 1, 1)
```

This is _nexContractDate declaration:

```
   Private _nextContactDate As DateTime
```

It's weird for me. Comapre datetime to string?

Comment: it is better that you compare your variable with DateTime.MinValue, and use MinValue of DateTime as initial value.

Comment: @masoud ramezani: This isn't always desirable when working with dates in a database; as such, SQL min-value is `1, 1, 1753`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What this code is doing is extracting the date part (i.e. removing the time part) and using VB's loose nature to allow a date represented as a string to be implicitly converted back to a date for the purposes of comparison with an actual date.

The correct way to remove the time part would be to check as follows:

```
_nextContactDate.Date > new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
```

It seems odd, as this means that the 1st Jan 1900 will fail this check, and only dates from the 2nd Jan 1900 will pass. As such, I'd be inclined to check whether this code has a logic error.

Comment: The VB code could do this too. It would be faster, less 'smelly' and wouldn't rely on `Option Strict` being off and the weak typing that allows. +1 (Please ignore my previous mispalced and deleted comment)

Comment: Absolutely - there's no reason the VB code should be written the way it is. (have also deleted my previous comment as it made no sense now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but why compare a `DateTime` to a `string` anyway, why not just compare dates?

```
if (_nextContactDate > new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
{

}
```

As noted by Greg, currently the `ToShortDateString` removes some parts of the date (specifically, the time units), but upon comparison with a minimum date as such, this is rather redundant - if you are concerned at such a level, then you can compare only the `Date` members.

Comment: lets imagine `_nextContactDate` is some time on the 1st of January 1900, in this case your code would return a different result to the VB.net code above.

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't need to compare DataTime variable in string format.
you can compare like below:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2011,8,24);

if(myDate > DateTime.MinValue)
    DoSomething();
```

Comment: So, what is the `MinValue` of `DateTime`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx

Comment: but not the start of the 1st of January 1900. So not an equivalent conversion of the code in the OP.

Comment: please see my comment in question's comments

Answer (score 0):

In many databases, time is stored as the minimum date + the time value.

So assuming the minimum date is 31 Dec 1899 2359H (if I reckon right, that's the minimum for Access) then 1300H will be stored as 01 Jan 1900 1300H.
Dates are stored as 'usual'. And dates with time components have the date value with the time component attached to them.

What's this got to do with the code? The original programmer is trying to determine whether the field is holding a date or a time value. The analogy is simple. If the value is time only, then by stripping off the time component, you'll be left with 01 Jan 1900. If it contains a date component, it's going to be more than 01 Jan 1900.

Comment: Sorry if my answer's formatting looks awful. I'm using my phone's browser.

Comment: I use this technique too when working with fields that holds a date and/or time.